# This slow MySQL Query needs improvement

Tags: mysql, sql

This query works and provides me with the information I need, but it is very slow: it takes 18 seconds to agregate a database of only 4,000 records.
I'm bringing it here to see if anyone has any advice on how to improve it.

```
SELECT COUNT( status ) AS quantity, status 
FROM log_table
WHERE time_stamp
IN (SELECT MAX( time_stamp ) FROM log_table GROUP BY userid )
GROUP BY status
```

Here's what it does/what it needs to do in plain text:

I have a table full of logs, each log contains a "userid", "status" (integer between 1-12) and "time_stamp" (a time stamp of when the log was created). There may be many entries for a particular userid, but with a different time stamp and status. I'm trying to get the most recent status (based on time_stamp) for each userid, then count the occurrences of each most-recent status among all the users.

My initial idea was to use a sub query with GROUP BY userid, that worked fast - but that always returned the *first* entry for each userid, not the *most recent*. If I could do GROUP BY userid using time_stamp DESC to Identify which row should be the representative for the group, that would be great. But of course ORDER BY inside of group does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please prepend `EXPLAIN` to your query and post the results here? (i.e. in MySQL client or phpMyAdmin run `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(status) ....`)

Comment: Do you have an index on the time_stamp field as well as status? index will make joins / searches / groupings etc faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to try is to make this an explicit `join`:

```
SELECT COUNT(status) AS quantity, status 
FROM log_table join
     (select lg.userid, MAX( time_stamp ) as maxts
      from log_table lg
      GROUP BY userid
     ) lgu
     on lgu.userid = lg.userid and lgu.maxts = lg.time_stamp
GROUP BY status;
```

Another approach is to use a different `where` clause.  This will work best if you have an index on `log_table(userid, time_stamp)`.  This approach is doing the filtering by saying "there is no timestamp bigger than this one for a given user":

```
SELECT COUNT(status) AS quantity, status 
FROM log_table
WHERE not exists (select 1
                  from log_table lg2
                  where lgu.userid = lg.userid  and lg2.time_stamp > lg.time_stamp
                 )
GROUP BY status;
```